# Prevent div jump to next line if it doesn't fit

Tags: css

Is there any way to prevent div3 from being wrapped to the next line and instead of vertical scrolling do horizontal?

```
<table>
<tr>

  <td>td1</td>

  <td>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">div1</div>
        <div class="inner">div2</div>
        <div class="inner">div3</div>
    </div>
  </td>

</tr>
</table>


table { width: 400px; height: 100px; }
td { width: 50%; border: 1px solid gray; }

div.container { height: 100px; width: 100%; background: red; overflow-x: scroll; }

div.inner { height: 100px; width: 80px; display: block; float: left; background: blue; color: #fff; }
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wz13kLs5/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with floats you can't have scroll on the horizontal axis because if a floating element can't fit in the remaining space it will fall to the next line.

So we have to treat the divs as inline level blocks and set `white-space:nowrap` to prevents divs from breaking to next line.

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /* added */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* to remove space between divs */
  font-size: 0;
}

div.inner {
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  
  /*display: block; removed */
  /*float: left; removed */

  
  /* added */
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* because font size in inherited it will be set to 0
     but we want text to apear 
  */
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">div1</div>
        <div class="inner">div2</div>
        <div class="inner">div3</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Vv. my bad i don't use tables much to fix that issue you just add `table-layout: fixed;` to the table to prevent the browser from interfering

Answer (score 1):

if you need only 3 divs and you are using bootstrap you can do something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>

  <td>td1</td>

  <td>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-3">div1</div>
        <div class="col-3">div2</div>
        <div class="col-3">div3</div>
    </div>
  </td>

</tr>
</table>
```

css

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wz13kLs5/3/)

bootstrap grid-system split each row in 12 columns by default, may you want to take a look to their documentation: [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: inline-block adds padding between divs

Comment: this is why I used 3 columns and not 4, you can remove the padding using p-0 on divs or adding padding:0; to css

Comment: they are inline-block due to css and inline-block can have padding: https://medium.com/@DaphneWatson/css-display-properties-block-inline-and-inline-block-how-to-tell-the-difference-7d3a1e6e3051

Answer (score 0):

Add `<br>` to your code:

```
<table>
<tr>

  <td>td1</td>
<br>
  <td>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">div1</div>
<br>
        <div class="inner">div2</div>
<br>
        <div class="inner">div3</div>
    </div>
  </td>

</tr>
</table>
```